# Merge two mirroring Pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas

I need to be able to merge two columns which 'mirror' each other, creating a new column which holds the value from 'dest' in the case of 'A' and 'src' in the case of 'B'.

I currently have:

```
src    dest    type     time
  1       2       A       76
  1       3       A      176
  1       4       A      276
  1       5       A      376
  2       1       B      211
  3       1       B      321
  4       1       B      422
  5       1       B      523
```

And need to transform this into:

```
 id    type    time
  2       A      76
  2       B     211
  3       A     176
  3       B     311
  4       A     276
  4       B     411
  5       A     376
  5       B     511
```

I was originally thinking I needed to use pivot_table() but I don't think that will work in this situation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and last remove unnecessary columns:

*Notice - solution wotking for 2 types - `A` and `B`*

```
df['id'] = np.where(df['type'] == 'B', df['src'], df['dest'])
df = df.sort_values(['id','type']).drop(['src','dest'], 1)
print (df)
  type  time  id
0    A    76   2
4    B   211   2
1    A   176   3
5    B   321   3
2    A   276   4
6    B   422   4
3    A   376   5
7    B   523   5
```